# Can't INSERT INTO SELECT into a table with identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, identity-column

In SQL server, I'm using a table variable and when done manipulating it I want to insert its values into a real table that has an identity column which is also the PK.

The table variable I'm making has two columns; the physical table has four, the first of which is the identity column, an integer IK. The data types for the columns I want to insert are the same as the target columns' data types.

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Message] ([Name], [Type])
 SELECT DISTINCT [Code],[MessageType] 
 FROM @TempTableVariable
```

This fails with:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Message' with unique index
>       'IX_Message_Id'. The duplicate key value is (ApplicationSelection).

But when trying to insert just Values (...) it works ok.

How do I get it right?

Comment: Can you post the schema of dbo.Message?

Comment: You're probably missing an auto-increment declaration on `Message.Id`

Comment: `Message.Id` is identity and its identity increment is 1. That should be enough to do that, right? Otherwise I wouldn't be able to insert using the `Values(...)` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the data "ApplicationSelection" is already in the database. YOu need to write the select to exclude records that are already in the database. YOu can do that with a where not exists clause or a left join. LOok up teh index to see what field is unique besides the identity. That will tell you what feild you need to check to see if teh record currently exists.

Comment: `'ApplicationSelection'` isn't in the DB. And the table key is Id.

Comment: then you have applicationSelection in your query twice probably with two differnt values for the other field. It may not be the key but it appears to have a unique index.